# Angular date validation based on cross field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a angular reactive form in which i want to validate the Admission Date such that it's minimum date is Birth Date, How can i validate it based on cross field

component ts:

```
    ngOnInit(){
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'birthDate':[''],
      'admissionDate': ['']
      });
    }
    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-plan-admission-date',
      template: 
  <div  class="form-group">
    <label>Admission Date</label>

    <input type="text" [formControl]="admissionDateControl" class="form-control"  />
  </div>

    })
    export class AdmissionDateComponent  {
      @Input() admissionDateControl:AbstractControl;
    }
```

Html:

```
<div>
  <div class="container">
  <main class="col-12"><h3 class="bd-title" id="content">Cross Field Validation Date</h3>
<br>
<form  [formGroup]="userForm">
<div  class="form-group">
    <label>Birth Date</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="birthDate" class="form-control"  />

</div>
<app-plan-admission-date [admissionDateControl]="userForm.controls.admissionDate"></app-plan-admission-date>

<button [disabled]="!userForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form></main>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way i can validate `date` using cross field without making custom validation in `angular`

Stackblitz :https://stackblitz.com/edit/cross-field-date-validation-in-angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making custom validation function you can use minDate validation of @rxweb 
Here is the code :

```
ngOnInit(){
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'birthDate':[''],
  'admissionDate': ['',RxwebValidators.minDate({fieldName:"birthDate"})]
  });
 }
}
```

Here is the [forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cross-field-date-validation-in-angular-nvzuzy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can do that via custom validator, it should look something like this (validation of dates aside):

```
export function DateMoreThan(controlName: string, thanControlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
    const thanControl = formGroup.controls[thanControlName];

    if (control.errors && !control.errors.mustBeMoreThan) {
      return;
    }

    if (new Date(control.value) < new Date(thanControl.value)) {
      control.setErrors({ mustBeMoreThan: true });
    } else {
      control.setErrors(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Where we compare date from control with name `controlName` to control with name `thanControlName`. Here is working [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cross-field-date-validation-in-angular-aphby7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Hope that helps.

Comment: I want some other way to validate, I want want to make custom validation function @Amir

Comment: This is a custom validation function, take a look on example, and see how it's being registered into formcontrol

Comment: I don't want to use custom validation function Because my form have lots of fields and it’s not the recommended way to put the validator on formgroup level, do you have any other alternatives?

Comment: You can do that using service, for example, but you would need to manually set errors for controls.

Answer (score 0):

if you make a validation over a control, you can use parent to get the formGroup

```
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'birthDate':['11/12/2016'],
  'admissionDate': ['11/12/2016',DateMoreThan('birthDate')]
  });
}

export function DateMoreThan(thanControlName: string) {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    if (!control.parent)
      return null
    const formGroup=control.parent as FormGroup;
    const thanControl = formGroup.controls[thanControlName];

    if (thanControl)
    {
       const [day, month, year] = control.value.split("/")
       const [day2, month2, year2] = thanControl.value.split("/")
       return new Date(year2,month2-1,day2).getTime()>new Date(year,month-1,day).getTime()?
           { mustBeMoreThan: true }:null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in below example, we can create a custom validator in order to compare two fields dueDate and repeatUntilDate. And then we can apply this validator to the formGroup instance present in component class. For more detailed explanation on how to use custom validator for reactive forms, have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ql_GS5TJOeo).

```
export const dateValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: FormGroup) : ValidationErrors | null => {
  const dueDate = control.get('dueDate');
  const recurrenceType = control.get('recurrenceType');
  const repeatUntil = control.get('repeatUntil');

  return dueDate && recurrenceType && repeatUntil && recurrenceType.value != 'NONE'
  && dueDate.value >= repeatUntil.value ? {dueDateGtEqRepeatUntil: true} : null;
};
```